# SubSonic 2.2 Scaffolding in MVC 1

Tags: subsonic

Can anyone point me to a doc on how to get Subsonic's 2.2 scaffolding working in MVC 1. Or, does Subsonic's 2.2 scaffolding even work in MVC 1?

Love this software btw...Thanks Rob and others.

Answer (score 2):

The scaffold stuff is a Server Control so in short - it won't work (MVC doesn't support controls).

That said you can use the MVC tooling to create what you need in short order...